# Yii urlManager unlimited parameters

Tags: php, yii

is there is a way in yii to make parameters unlimited

for example, i have module /admin/

```
'urlManager'=>array(
  'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'caseSensitive'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
      '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
      '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
      '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',                
      'admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'admin/<controller>/<action>',
      'admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'admin/<controller>/<action>',          
    ),
  ),
```

and within admin module i need that every action could have unlimited parameters, for example:

```
 /admin/anycontroller/anyaction/anything
 /admin/anycontroller/anyaction/anything/anything2
 /admin/anycontroller/anyaction/anything/anything2/anything3
 /admin/anycontroller/anyaction/anything/anything2/anything3/anything4 
 ... and so on
```

should i define it one by one on the rules? or there is shortcut to do this?

and how to catch it on the controller action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a shortcut:

```
'admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/*'=>'admin/<controller>/<action>'
```

i.e append the rule with a `/*`

Since this is a more general rule, which can catch a lot of urls, it would be better to have it at the bottom, or atleast after any specific rules, i.e:

```
// ... other specific rules ...
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>', // specifically for id
// ... other specific rules ...
'admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/*'=>'admin/<controller>/<action>'
```

For your case:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'admin/<controller>/<action>',
'admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'admin/<controller>/<action>',
'admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/*'=>'admin/<controller>/<action>'
```

---

To catch it in the action, just don't specify any parameters for the action, like so:

```
public function actionSomething() {
    // instead use $_GET
    $params=$_GET;

}
```

But it should also work with the definition that you already have: `public function actionAnyAction($id=0,$type='',$type2='')`

Comment: hmm, what happens when you use it inside module? edit: as in what sort of urls do you get, if you use createUrl? or something else that tells you that it isn't working?

Comment: it's 404 when i tried admin/anycontroller/anyaction/12/anything

Comment: but it's ok when i use this rule:
'admin/anycontroller/anyaction/<id:\d+>/<type:\w+>'=>'admin/anycontroller/anyaction'
and
'admin/anycontroller/anyaction/<id:\d+>/<type:\w+>/<type2:\w+>'=>'admin/anycontroller/anyaction'
and so on

Comment: same 404, ah my bad.. it's because the action in the controller does not catch it automatically function action actionAnyAction($id=0,$type='',$type2='')